# Bitbucket pipeline override a trigger from manual to automatic

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Ive got a step definition which has a trigger manual currently set, but in certain cases in the pipeline, id like that to be changed to automatic. Is there a way i can change this trigger without having to create a whole new definition where only the trigger is different?

In my pipeline i was hoping something like the below would work, but it doesnt seem to be making any difference

```
pipelines:
   specific-branch:
      - step: *Deploy-Development
          trigger: automatic
```

Answer (score 1):

That YAML syntax is not correct. I do it like

```
definitions:
  yaml-anchors:

    - &deploy-step
        script:
          - bash deploy.sh $BITBUCKET_DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT

pipelines:
  branches:

    main:

      - step:
          <<: *deploy-step
          name: Deploy dev
          deployment: test
          trigger: automatic

      - step:
          <<: *deploy-step
          name: Deploy prod
          deployment: production
          trigger: manual
```

Is this what you are trying to achieve?